# Can I represent a chromosome in nlopt?

Tags: c++, nlopt

I want to find the best solution for a problem. However, the solution(chromosome) is represented as a vector of integers (length unknown).

As far as I know, NLOPT accepts `double*` as an input. Furthermore, the number of attributes is a `constant`. So is it possible to wrap around and pass a `std::vector<int>`?

**EDIT** - Tiny desciption of the problem:

I have a set of points. I want to sort this point using a heuristic. This  heuristic is some what complex. It is the less possible number of crossing lines between them if we draw line between each consecutive points. I was thinking of something close to the gentic algorithm where I can represent the solution as chromosome of the ordered indexes.

I pick NLOPT because I have very successful previous experiment with it. I know it could be solved using many other genetic or bees algorithms libraries. But here I am asking about NLOPT it self.

Comment: Com on!, How am I asking for recommendation a library!

Comment: Seems like a reasonable question to me, OP is trying to establish how to make NLOPT and the standard libraries connect together for him. I don't see a request for a library and I do see a clear question.

Comment: We seem to be establishing that that your question is okay - it would be easier to understand if you explained more fully what you are doing and WHY you need the vector<int>.

Comment: Looks great - pity I don't know the answers - I'm sure someone out there does...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `vector<int>` as input, but your library take a `double*` and a constant size.

You could do something like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{

  std::vector<int> iVector = {1, 2, 3, 4};
  std::vector<double> dVector;

  dVector.resize(iVector.size());

  std::transform(iVector.begin(), iVector.end(), dVector.begin(), [&] (auto i) -> double { return static_cast<double>(i); } );

  for (auto d : dVector)
  {
      std::cout << d << std::endl;
  }

  std::cout << &dVector[0] << std::endl;

}
```

You can access the vector data with `&dVector[0]` as a `double *`. The constant size by `dVector.size()` it remains valid until the vector doesn't modify its internal storage.

You surely need to convert back the data, you can do it using the same principle.

**EDIT**

Otherwise, there is an NLopt C++ reference that wraps directly the C API so you can pass directly a `vector<double>`.

Juste include `#include <nlopt.hpp>` to call nlopt in a C++ way.

See : http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt_C-plus-plus_Reference

Comment: Thanks, dVector.size() is not a constant it may change internally

Comment: Maybe you could directly use the nlopt c++ interface, see my edit.